# How com.sun.tools.javac.Main.javac use the same classpath with springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want use the `com.sun.tools.javac.Main.javac` in a springboot application,But when the java code which need be compiled need import some jar(such as guava) it throws the `ClassNotFoundException`.

**EDIT**

`com.sun.tools.javac.Main` class is in 'tools.jar'.

Here is the code:

```
com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(new String[]{"xxx.java"})
```

Comment: 1. I cannot find `javac` method under `com.sun.tools.javac.Main`. 2. You need to show us how you are using it.  Spawning a new process? Or calling the `main` directly as a normal method?

Comment: @AdrianShum,I edited the content.Thank you.

Comment: I believe you need to provide `-cp classpath` to the command

Comment: @AdrianShum,yes,i need `-classpath`,but springboot application just a big jar.All jars are in the `BOOT_INF/lib`,Except i unzip the jar,and point the `classpath`

Comment: Unless it is using a custom-made classloader, they should have been extracted somewhere.

Comment: What scope are the jars you are getting class not found exceptions ?

Unless they are runtime they won't be available to compile against at runtime.